# FontAwesome caret down does not appear in ngClass

Tags: angular

I have a strange issue where I need to show the fontawesome caret up and down on sorting the field.But only the fa-caret-up is shown but not fa-caret-down.I am using the below code.

**HTML**

```
 <th (click)="sort('ref')">Ref {{reverse}}
    <span *ngIf="sortKey=='ref'"  ><i  [ngClass]="{'fa fa-caret-down':reverse,'fa fa-caret-up':!reverse}" ></i></span>
 </th>
```

TS

```
     sortKey:string = "";
     reverse:boolean = true;

  sort(field){
    this.sortKey = field;
    this.reverse = !this.reverse;

  }
```

On Inspecting the html generated I observe that fa is not concatenated when fa-caret-down.But it is concatenated when fa-caret-up is shown.Is this a bug in Angular 4?

I also tried concatenating the class="fa" before it with no difference.Please Clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is strange, when reverse is true, it removes fa class from fa-caret-down.

This works,

```
<span><i class="fa" [ngClass]="{'fa-caret-down':reverse,'fa-caret-up':!reverse}" ></i></span>
```

edit: also you can use,

```
<span><i [ngClass]="reverse ? 'fa fa-caret-down': 'fa fa-caret-up'" ></i></span>
```